# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL PHP heredoc

Tags: php, heredoc

I keep getting the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_SL in /home/a4999406/public_html/willingLog.html on line 70

on the following code (first line is line 70):

```
        echo <<<END 
<form action = "willingLog.html" method="post"><pre>
    First       <input type="text" name="first" />
    Last        <input type="text" name="last" />
    Email       <input type="text" name="email" />
    Username    <input type="text" name="user_name" />
                <input type="submit" value="AD RECORD" />
</pre></form>
END;
```

heredoc just doesn't seem to work.  i've tried other examples.

following is by doctype heading.  is there something wrong there?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Comment: Are there any funky invisible characters in there, or any syntax problems *before* that?

Comment: no invisible characters.  no syntax issue above that I'm aware of.

Comment: `T_SL` stands for the `<<` bitwise operator... weird.

Comment: Not *too* weird; one common reason for this error is a coder only uses two "<" instead of the requisite 3 for the HEREDOC delimiter.

Hard to spot, too ;-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looking at the copy-paste, it looks like you have a space character after the word "END" on the first line:

```
'echo <<<END '
```

Try getting rid of the space character. Answer found by Googling. Source (link now dead): http://www.alexxoid.com/blog/dev/php-dev/php-parse-error-unexpected-t_sl.html

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo <<<'END'
<form action = "willingLog.html" method="post"><pre>
    First       <input type="text" name="first" />
    Last        <input type="text" name="last" />
    Email       <input type="text" name="email" />
    Username    <input type="text" name="user_name" />
                <input type="submit" value="AD RECORD" />
</pre></form>
END;
```

Comment: In my case work correctly, can you say something more? Any errors?

Comment: And remember you MUST NO any white chars after `echo <<<'END'`

Comment: @Piotr Looks like that's the actual problem...!

Comment: removing a space after END did the trick, I think.  Ran right into another bug, so I'll have to see.